# React/Flux: 1 Event Synchronously Updating Multiple Stores

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

React 0.14.0, Vanilla Flux Pattern

**Question: 
What if a triggered event needs to update 2 data structures that live in 2 separate stores?**

This is a very fundamental pain that I feel with Flux.

You logically decompose your stores, and then one day you find yourself creating an event, but unfortunately it needs simultaneously update 2 separate data structures that live in 2 different stores.(crap)

**Why that confuses me during development:**

Please Correct Me If This Logic Is Wrong

As far as my understanding of Flux goes, we should not dispatch an Action until the re-rendering caused by the previous action is complete. Therefore multiple synchronous actions to update a store(or multiple stores) is a flux no-no.

**My Solutions:**

**Crunch Stores Together -**
I can move the data that needs to be updated into the same store in order to keep it to one action.(that sounds like over complicating a store)

**Move State Server-Side -**
I can keep track of some of the state server-side, and then I can use  asynchronous action calls that update the server first and then the server pushes the update back to the store.(Sounds unRESTful and slow)

I'm a dedicated React developer, and am open to any advice and/or correction to help my understanding to build great React applications. Thx

Comment: This is what [the `waitFor` "escape hatch" is for](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/dispatcher.html#api). That link shows some examples of separate but dependent stores.

Comment: Also, if you just need to update the two stores *separately*, that is fine — the one action can cause both stores to update. However, if the stores need to update *together* (e.g. one needs internal knowledge of the other), then `waitFor` is what you need.

Comment: Note that if two stores both trigger a setState (by emitting an EventEmitter event in response to an action), if the source of the action was not a React component event, then you'll get two renders happening - one of the renders will be a) useless and possibly b) fail due to the inconsistent store state after only 1 store has updated. ReactDOM.unstable_batchedUpdates is the solution.

Comment: @MichelleTilley I thought ```waitFor``` was forcing one action to complete before letting another(more than likely dependent) execute.                         My worry is just firing 2 synchronous-store-updating actions and the second trying to emit a change before the re-rendering of the first is complete. I thought this was the whole reasoning behind my endless "dispatch invariant" issues with Flux.

Comment: @NickPineda If the two actions are dispatched back to back / at the same time, it's not a problem. If one of the action dispatches is *caused by* the other, that's a cascading dispatch and is not allowed. But `dispatch(action1); dispatch(action2);` is fine.

Comment: @MichelleTilley oh that shifted my understanding of flux greatly, and makes much more sense. So its if the re-rendering triggers an action that we have to watch out for?

Comment: @NickPineda You're on the right track, though not necessarily the rerendering — it's when, while handling an action dispatch, you dispatch a second action. Having an action dispatch go out as part of a rerender *can* be a problem if `batchedUpdates` is not used properly.

Comment: @MicelleTilley To clarify - I interpret "handling an action dispatch" as being in the middle of executing a setter method  inside the store. Looking at it that way- calling 2 synchronous actions to the same store,or more likely, an async callback triggering an action while the previous action is being handled would cause a dispatch error. Where am I going wrong with my understanding?